# Facebook profile URL to ID using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a couple of hundred Facebook profile URLs that I each want to convert to corresponding profile IDs. I have worked with Twitter which has an API call that does similar in batch of 100 (rate limited).

Is there a similar call with Facebook API? 1:1 would be sufficient if no batch support exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no legal way to turn profile URLs into IDs. You would need to scrape the profiles, which is not allowed on Facebook. The only serious way to get the ID of users is to authorize them with a Facebook App.